# Where to place dependencies in a Maven Enterprise Application?

Tags: java, maven, ejb, jakarta-ee

I've created a Maven Java Enterprise application which contains an EJB application and a Web application. In the Netbeans 'Projects' tab it shows both of these application projects as well as the Enterprise application that uses both of the above.

Should I place and dependencies in the Enterprise Application dependency folder or only in the Web or EJB project as required? What's the purpose of having the dependencies folder in the Enterprise project?

Answer (score 0):

An EJB project does not have a /lib folder, so all it's dependencies must be added in another archive.  The WAR project's dependencies can be put into /WEB-INF/lib.  What you'll generally find in the EAR archive's /lib folder are the dependencies required by the EJB project.  Remember that you don't need to actually include any of the JavaEE libraries (use the "provided" scope in Maven).